# Show content of classes in the admin site in a list

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I got a class with some variables which I of course can add change and delete in the admin interface. My aim is, to make the admin interface now a bit more user friendly and more obvious. I want to show the content of the variables on the page in the form of a list for example. When I wrote my views and templates for something else, I just rendered a dictionary to my template, iterated through it with the for tag and showed the data simply like this:

```
{% for _name in name %}
<li>{{ name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The Users of my app will work with the admin inerface and I want to make it better to understand for the users. I already got the templates and the stylesheets in my project, in a seperated template and static directory.

Edit: 
My class

```
class completedTask(models.Model):
        trainee = models.ForeignKey(trainee, verbose_name = "Azubi")
        learningObjectivecompletedTask = models.ManyToManyField(learningObjective, verbose_name = "Lernziel")
        date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Datum',blank=True)
        duration = models.TimeField(verbose_name = 'Dauer')
        documentationReference = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Dokumentationsverweis')
        educationDepartment = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Ausbildungsabteilung')
        class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Ausgeführte Tätigkeit"
                verbose_name_plural = "Ausgeführte Tätigkeiten"
```

Edit my admin.py already looks like this:

```
class completedTasks(admin.ModelAdmin):
        def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
                self.exclude = []
                if "Azubi" in request.user.groups.values_list("name", flat=True):
                        self.exclude.append('trainee')
                return super(completedTasks, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(completedTask, completedTasks)
```

I want to display every trainee for example in form of a list in my admin page.

Comment: Not clear from the description what type of class you have and what type of data this class holds. Put some sample data or some screenshot  to make things easier to understand.

Comment: Ok I did it. Here is an example of how one of my classes looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making use of the built in Django admin, you can display more information on the list view (i.e. `/admin/myapp/mymodel/`) by making use of the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) option of your `ModelAdmin`

For example, in the following list view (of the `auth.User` model) you can see extra inforamtion (email, first name, last name, staff ...):

[image]

In your case, in your `admin.py`:

```
class TraineeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'educationBeginning', 'comment',]

admin.site.register(Trainee, TraineeAdmin)
```

Comment: So what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to show the content of a variable in the form of a list. For example I want to show every trainee or so. Is that even possible with out inventing the wheel again ?

Comment: Adding the code above will give you a listing of all the trainees at /admin/your_app_name/trainee/

Comment: Well okay that seem to work :D but can you tell me as well how I can make the first site that appears, when you logged in, to a site that display more list of variables of diferrent models ? Or do you know how flexible I can be with that and whether I could do that list in a template as well and not in the admin.py ?

Comment: You need to read through [the documentation to get a feel for how the admin works.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) Remember it's just an another application. There are lots of ways to work with and extend the admin and it's functionality. You can [override templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) or add [custom views for example.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites)

Comment: I already had a look at overriding templates but didn't look at custom views. Thank you for your links